# How can i use multiple SSL certificate with one IP:PORT on IIS 8

Tags: asp.net, ssl, iis, ssl-certificate

I have 2 domains (www.domain1.com, www.domain2.com). For both, I have a separate certificate. Both domains have the same IP, but different host headers. How can I add https with cert1 to domain1 and https with cert2 to domain2 (on the same IP)? I tried to work around but didn't help me.

one www.domain1.com binding I have selected https then I have given the hostname as www.domain1.com then I have checked the SNI checkbox then I have selected the domain1 SSL.

Same steps I have done for www.domain2.com but when I run domain2.com it uses the SSL of domain1 since both domains have the same IP I don't know where I am missing my steps. You help will be much appreciated

Comment: You can use the Server Name Indication for this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-server-name-indication-sni-ssl-scalability

Comment: Its possible with PowerShell & netsh to create the 2 bindings using different certificates.

Answer (score 1):

As per my knowledge, For Multiple Certificates installation using SNI, You do not require to enter the host name and check the SNI checkbox for the **primary domain** (www.domain1.com), But it is compulsory to enter the host name and check the **Require Server Name Indication box** for **second domain** (www.domain2.com).

Find more information from here:

https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/1159/37/certificate-installation-microsoft-iis-8x#multiple

However, I recommend you to use [Multi-Domain SSL certificate](https://www.cheapsslshop.com/uc-san-ssl-certificates) to protect multiple domains instead of using Multiple certificates.